# Affine sub-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A\subset\Bbb C^n$ be an affine variety of dimension $n-r$ and let $g_1,\dots,g_r\in I(A)$ such that $\text{rank}\{dg_1,\dots,dg_r\}=r$ on an open dense subset $U$ of $A$ (i.e., $A$ is complete intersection on $U$). Assume that the minor of the Jacobian matrix $J(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ of $(g_1,\dots,g_r)$, by deleting the last $m-r$ columns, is not identically zero on $A$. Then is $A\cap \{J(g_1,\dots,g_r,x_{r+1},\dots,x_n)=0\}$ an affine variety?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are there pieces of evidence making you think the answer is yes or no?

Comment: I'd like to know if the polar variety (including the singular set of $A$) of the projection from $A$ to a linear subspace of same dimension is still an affine variety. So maybe we have to choose $n-r$ generic linear forms (not just $x_{r+1},\dots,x_n$ which might not be generic).

Comment: The procedure you're describing is just adding some extra equations. It's affine, do an example.

Comment: How can you prove that it is affine? I cannot prove that the last polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Why would that matter? Usually, being an affine variety means that it's given as $\operatorname{Spec} R$ for some commutative ring $R$ which is finite type over a field - here, $A$ is given by $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$, and you're asking about $A\cap \{J(\cdots)=0\}$, given by the ideal $(I,J)$, which is therefore affine and given by $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(I,J)$. If you mean to ask about irreducibility and reducedness, you should say this. (Proving the last polynomial is irreducible might not be enough - intersection doesn't preserve irreducibility).

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is $A\cap\{\det J(g_1,\dots,g_r,x_{r+1},\dots,x_n)=0\}$, so we add only one equation. Does it change anything? For me $A$ is affine if $I(A)$ is prime.